# Error in partial layouts in rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this view:

```
<%= form_for(:subject, :url => { :action => 'update', :id => @subject.id}) do |f| %>
<%= render partial: "layouts/form" , locals: {:jex => f}  %>
```

And this form partial:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 form-padding "><%= jex.text_field(:name ,:class => "form-control") %></div>
    </div>
```

But, I have an error:

[image: undefined local variable or method `jex']

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace? (further down on the error page). Also when posting an image please crop away anything irrelevant such as the blank console, the tabs, and the icons to the left.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<%= render "layouts/form", jex: f %>
```